# Does sphinx api only support .wav file as input?

Tags: java, speech-recognition, cmusphinx

I want to try the sphinx api for the conversion of the .mp3 file to the text format. But I've read it somewhere that it only supports .wav file and since I've changed .mp3 file to .wav file it is giving me proper output. what if i want to do the processing directly on .mp3 file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mp3 recognition using Sphinx 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047475/mp3-recognition-using-sphinx-4)

Comment: what do u mean by duplicate of mp3 recognition.